# How to tell Flutter that a variable can be null in the right way (Null Safety)?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a question about Flutter and Null Safety.

For example I have this lines of code:

```
  Future<dynamic> isLoggedIn() async {
    Account account = Account(client);
    Response? result = await account.get();
    if (result == null) {
      print(true);
    }
  }
```

I've marked `result` as nullable variable with `Response?`. So `result` can be null. Why Visual Studio gives me the warning `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.`, if I check if `result == null`?

Do I misunderstand the concept of Null Safety? :-)

Comment: What type does `account.get()` return?

Comment: In general it's an object.

Comment: If `account.get()` can not return `null`, then it doesn't make sense to mark `result` as nullable, since it can never be `null`.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. But the request can return null from server side. So I can get null as result. That's the problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As also suggested by  julemand101, the behavior of your ide is due to the fact that, when a variable is set using a method that returns a non-nullable type, the dart analyzer knows with certainty that the variable is not null (despite the type with which you declared the variable would allow null).

I too was surprised a little by the warning, because if you declare the variable by specifying its type, instead of using `var`, I would expect the dart analyzer to understand that the intent of the developer is to guard against possible changes. Then, thinking about it, I realized that if the method changed the signature and returned a nullable type, the compiler would force the developer to perform a null check, so in fact there is no reason to execute such a check until it is really needed.

However, you can make the warning disappear by using the comment `// ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison` or through the file analysis_options.yaml:

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    unnecessary_null_comparison: ignore
```

Edit:

> the request can return null from server side.

If your `account.get()` method could return `null`, the ide would not report that warning to you. So I guess it's the signature of your  method which is incorrect.

However, as for the question in the title ("the right way to tell Flutter that a variable can be null"), by declaring the variable as nullable you are leaving yourself the option of re-evaluating the variable with null or with a nullable type (and in that case then the null check would make sense).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio gives you that warning because (I'm guessing because I did not see your get method) your get method is returning value that is not able to be a null value

```
Future<Response> get() async {
  ...
}
```

If you want it to be able to return null it should be declared like this

```
Future<Response?> get() async {
  ...
}
```